# Hyperledger Developer Guide Tutorial

Tags: npm, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I'm busy working through the Hyperledger developer guide to create the  business network (https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/tutorials/developer-guide.html). Everything works as documented, but as soon as I check that the structure of the files is valid using the commands:

$ cd my-network

$ npm install

I receive the error:

- 10 scenarios(10 failed)
- 78 steps(10 failed, 48 skipped, 20 passed)
- npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
- npm ERR! errno 1
- npm ERR! my-network@0.1.6 test-inner: 'mcha -t 0 --recursive && cucumber-js'
- npm ERR! Exit status 1
- npm ERR! Failed at the my-network@0.1.6 test-inner script.

Any help on how to solve this problem? Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Turned out I was using Ubuntu 17.04 instead of 16.04.